# Magento's admin scheduled backups makes multiple backups on the server

Tags: magento-1.9, backup

I have setup of **Database daily backup** every night at 12:30am, through Admin's System>Configuration>Advanced>System>Scheduled Backup Settings.

Magento backs up the data base. But it **creates 4 of the same backup files**, instead of just one. I started this two nights ago, and it has done it consistently for the past 2 nights.  4 database backups every night at around 12:30, 12:31, 12:32 and 12:33!

How can I stop that from happening and make it to create one back up file?

System>Configuration>Advanced>System>Cron (Scheduled Tasks)

Generate Schedules Every: 15
Schedule Ahead for: 20
Missed if Not Run Within: 15
History Cleanup Every: 10
Success History Lifetime: 60
Failure History Lifetime: 600

The following is the cron i have on the server:

`*  *   *   *   *   wget -O /dev/null -q http://domainDOTcom/path/to/magento/cron.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things here.

1. Never use the inbuilt backup tool. Its flawed in far too many ways to be useful. Instead, use conventional server tools to dump the DB and backup the files.

   Eg. Some Magento specific tools for DB dumping

   - [mage-dbdump](http://sys.sonassi.com/mage-dbdump.sh)
   - [magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/wiki/Stripped-Database-Dumps)

   Or generic tools for MySQL dumping

   - [automysqlbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/)
   - [xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/) - *not recommended for novices*

   And for file backups, use things like `rsync` or `tar` to generate backups,

   Eg.

   - Using `tar`

     ```
     tar cvfz /path/to/backup.tgz /path/to/public_html \
       --exclude='/var/log' \
       --exclude='/var/session' \
       --exclude='/var/cache' \
       --exclude='/var/backup' \
       --exclude='/var/report' \
       --exclude='/media/catalog/product/cache'
     ```
   - Using `rsync`

     ```
     rsync -vPa /path/to/public_html/ /path/to/backup_html/  \
       --exclude='/var/log' \
       --exclude='/var/session' \
       --exclude='/var/cache' \
       --exclude='/var/backup' \
       --exclude='/var/report' \
       --exclude='/media/catalog/product/cache'
     ```
2. You should never execute your cron via `wget` - you should be using the `cron.sh` wrapper to execute it,

   ```
   * * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/public_html/cron.sh
   ```

Comment: I changed the cron from `*  *   *   *   *   wget -O /dev/null -q http://domainDOTcom/path/to/magento/cron.ph`' to `* * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/public_html/cron.sh`. What is difference between `wget` method and `cron.sh`? They both seem to work.  Also, any idea why **System>Configuration>Advanced>System>Scheduled Backup Settings** is making 4 database  backups?

Comment: There's loads of reasons. 1. No job control when run via wget, which means your cron will overlap and run multiple times. 2. Security, crons shouldn't be run in the context of a web server. 3. Newer versions of Magento require arguments to be passed to cron.php to dictate the type of cron being run.

Comment: Regarding backups. **Do not use the built in tool - it is broken**.

Comment: Since you mentioned Magento's admin backup is broken, I decided to look into mage-dbdump, magerun. These solutions are great but they strip some table from the database. I need full backups. If I use any other generic backup solutions or even MySQL export, They do NOT place the [foreign key constraints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/restoring_a_backup_of_a_magento_database), Magento requires  and places at the beginning and at the end of .sql file.  Is their a solution that does this and can be automated, through server cron?  I hope I am making sense?

Comment: `mage-dbump` is a tool built specifically to create Magento DB dumps and restore them. Its used thousands of times per day - trust me when I say its the exact tool you should be using :) If you use the `-f` parameter, it won't strip tables, eg. `mage-dbdump.sh -f` - however, my advice would be to use it with its defaults. The tables that are stripped are only logs - and would be useless on a staging/dev site - or worse still, would delay the import of the DB it is for live. My best advice would be to use `automysqlbackup` - or swap hosting providers to one that actually provides backups.

Comment: Got it will give it try. Cheers.

Comment: I tried mage-dbdump, very nice and fast. Full dump `bash mage-dbdump.sh -f` and `bash mage-dbdump.sh -fz` do Not work.  When command is issued, I get the help menu!  But  `bash mage-dbdump.sh -dz` and `bash mage-dbdump.sh -d` work fine. Is it possible to have a time stamp in the name of db.sql?

Comment: What is wrong with executing `wget` in a cron? Would you explain.

Comment: There's loads of reasons. 1. No job control when run via wget, which means your cron will overlap and run multiple times. 2. Security, crons shouldn't be run in the context of a web server. 3. Newer versions of Magento require arguments to be passed to cron.php to dictate the type of cron being run.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The reason why I asked the question was, I am having a hell of time with e-mails getting queued up to get sent out.  Add it was working with `wget`.  Now I'm using `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /home/public_html/magento/cron.sh` in the cron and it's not sending any emails out (they are NOT even getting queued up in cron_schedule table! It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Speak to your web host. It should be a 5 second fix.

Comment: It's solved.  It took me a while, but I found out that the `cron.sh` has to be executable.  And I also had to define an absolute link `PHP_BIN`. Thanks for your help, very useful.

Comment: Remember that Magento upgrades reset file permissions. So its best using `/bin/bash /path/to/cron.sh` - which mitigates the requirement for executable permissions :)